# Windows network routing

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, routing

I'm working by my customer premises and they let me connect my private laptop on a dedicated Wi-Fi for internet access. It's nice for external consultants. The only issue is that we can't connect on a remote server on port 25. I suppose this policy is set up to avoid infected computers sending spam from their network.

As you can have guessed, this is something weird that I can't send mail at all. Fortunately, I've a 3G cell phone that I can connect by Bluetooth on my laptop. So when I want to send an e-mail, I have to disconnect from Wi-Fi, connect my phone, send the e-mail, disconnect phone and reconnect Wi-Fi. Kinda overhead.

My question is: how can I tell Windows 7 to use the Wi-Fi for every out connection, but if it's a connection on port 25, use the cell phone network? With this solution, I could let my phone connected all day without having to switch again and again.

Thanks a lot for your anwwers.
Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the below only if you know what you are doing.

- first open an admin right cmd.exe
  (i.e. windows key -> "cmd" then right click "cmd" and click "run as administrator")
- run `route print` (this should show the interfaces)
- then run `route add dest mask  netmask gateway metric metric IF ifcode`
  where dest = destination (the mail server), mask = netmask (in your case is a single IP), gateway is the default gateway of the phone, metric (a small one), and ifcode the interface of your phone.

hope that helps

Comment: Can we add a route only for a specific port and not a destination host?

Comment: @fabianvilers No, the routing table only handles IP addresses. You would need a NAT/firewall which supports routing based on port to do that. I'm afraid I don't know any off the top of my head for Windows.

Comment: @fabianvilers, i think that is a limitation of window's routing system. @Darth Android is correct.

Comment: It's not exactly a _limitation_ - IP routing only deals with IP addresses. Ports (TCP or UDP) are on a higher level.

Comment: @grawity, i do agree with you that IP routing only deals with IP addresses, but policy-based routing (as in cisco routers) supports port, of course, so when we are talking about routing capability (in general), i think calling it a limitation is not exactly wrong :)

Comment: @bubu: Well, a consumer-oriented OS rarely needs the same set of capabilities as specialized Cisco hardware.

Comment: @grawity - okay, okay. I agree with you. :)